# Leafletjs draggable попап с формой внутри исчезает из DOM

Tags: leafletjs, mapbox

По клику на карте появляется маркер, у которого есть `popup`. Маркер `draggable`. Когда начинаешь тянуть маркер - попап исчезает. Это даже хорошо - сам попам не мешает точнее целиться маркером. После того как мы закончили тянуть - попап появляется обратно. Но есть один нюанс - в попапе форма с полями ввода, и когда попап исчезает при драге - он вырезается из `DOM`, а потом возвращается девственно чистым. То есть пользователь, заполнивший форму наполовину после драга получает чистую форму. в документации ничего не нашел по поводу того чтобы попап просто скрывался, не вырезаясь. Какими методами (даже грязными) можно это исправить?

```
$('.add-place').click(function(){

    //координаты центра карты
    addNewLat = map.getCenter().lat;
    addNewLng = map.getCenter().lng;

    //удаляем маркер, если он уже есть на карте
    if (typeof addMarker != 'undefined') {
        map.removeLayer(addMarker);
    }

    var addLatLng = L.latLng(addNewLat, addNewLng);

    // добавляем маркер с формой
    addMarker = L.marker(addLatLng, {
        icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-symbol': 'circle', 'marker-color': '00FFFF'}),
        draggable: true,
        zIndexOffset: 1000
    })
        .addTo(map)
        .bindPopup('<form class="infoAdd">'+$('.addTemplate').html()+'</form>', {
             closeButton: false, 
             minWidth: 320, 
             closeOnClick: false
        })
        .openPopup();

    // Показываем попап после окончания драга
    addMarker.on('dragend', function(e) {
        e.target.openPopup();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Остановился на методе, когда в переменную записываем `serialize` формы, и при появлении попапа с формой после `dragend` - делаем `unserialize` с помощью замечательного плагина https://github.com/Canta/unserialize

```
$(document).on('change','form#popupForm input',function(){
    input = $('form#popupForm').serialize();
});

addMarker.on('dragend', function(e) {
    e.target.openPopup();
    if (typeof input != 'undefined') {
        $("form#popupForm").unserialize(input);
    }
});
```